# Pivot 1 row n columns in excel to n rows 1 column

Tags: excel, pivot

Have I become stupid or is it really difficut to convert 1 row 80 columns in excel to 80 rows 1 column?

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the data, one of the paste options is "transpose".